# Как указать путь к файлу вне maven-модуля?

Tags: java, maven

Имеется следующая файловая структура, где модуль nested-maven-folder отмечен как подмодуль pom.xml top-maven-folder.

```
top-maven-folder    
......pom.xml    
......nested-special-folder    
......nested-maven-folder    
............pom.xml    
............some-file.xml    
............folder-with-java-classes
```

Как обратиться из класса в folder-with-java-classes к папке nested-special-folder?

Я рассуждал так: если обратиться к внутреннему файлу, к примеру, `some-file.xml` мы можем прямо вот так, написав его имя, то для вызова уровня выше мы пишем что-то вроде `..\nested-special-folder`.
Однако, это не сработало!

Comment: пока заюзал такой костыль, вроде работает.. `new File(".").getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
                + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "nested-special-folder"`

Comment: ./../nested-special-folder - вот так правильно =)